# Is it possible to see distance to a waypoint, along the current course?

Tags: garmin

I have a course created on GPSies that has a couple of waypoints, in this case it's pit stops, along the course. When I transfer it to my Edge 1000 through the `new files` folder I correctly get both the course and the waypoints.

However, once I start to ride along the course I can never see how far it is to the waypoints. All I can see is where it is on the map, or if I wish, I can stop the course and instead navigate to the waypoint.

I can also see how far away the waypoint is if I list all saved waypoints (called locations on the Edge 1000) along a straight line.

I'm I missing anything? This should be a very common usecase for long rides with pit stops, like organised races where you can refill water.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question. Yes, it's possible, but it's apparently not shown on the screen you use, with your current device. Can another device do it? Perhaps you could refine your question to get the answer to this question.

Comment: But is it needed? All Cycle Computers, apps, and devices that I've seen show the distance ridden. If you know the distance to each pitstop, subtracting current distance from the next pitstop distance tells you how far away it is.

Comment: That is how I do it now @andy256 it's just too many things to remember sometimes. This summer I'll be riding for 8 days, having 2-3 pitstops each day. I can't memorise each of those distances each day. I'd rather have the Edge just tell me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Edge 1000 PDF manual download](http://static.garmin.com/pumac/Edge_1000_OM_EN.pdf), there is a data field called **Time to Next** which should give you what you want. The manual says this gives you:

> The remaining distance to the next waypoint on the route. You must be
>   navigating for this to appear.

Comment: Hmm. The OP already says *I can stop the course and instead navigate to the waypoint*.

Comment: If I turn on turn-by-turn guidance Time/Distance to next is until the next turn. All of those waypoints added when the Edge maps the course to the map data. So it won't show distance to the waypoints I've created.